# How to deal with objects of classes that are irrelevant to the microservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, microservices, encapsulation

I am trying to divide a monolithic system into microservices using Spring Boot. The problem I encountered is that while each microservice should normally have classes that implement the service functionality, I need to receive and deal with objects that encapsulate many classes that are related to other microservices. For example, the code below is part of microservice1, which provides student information:

```
class Microservice1{

int id;
String name;
int grade;
Record record;

}
```

Notice now that the **Record** object is of a class that belongs to another microservice, which is microservice2, which provide student record as the following:

```
class Microservice2{

List<int> marks;
Behaviour behaviour;

}
```

Now **behaviour**  is also another object whose class belongs to another microservice 3, and so on.

My question is: How do I get rid of the issue of having to include all these classes in microservice 1 because microservice1 needs to deal with them while providing the service? The problem is serious because I have many encapsulated classes inside each other, and I would need to include most of the monolithic system classes in one microservice.

Comment: IMHO Bounded context concept can help you.

Comment: Just to clarify, may we assume that your problem is not wanting one microservice to have a dependency on class files from another microservice? +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can see, you are making your microservices way too granular. You'll have a lot of trouble implementing that way.

**IMHO**, if a `Record` is related to a `Student` **AND belongs to the same *business context***, they belong to the same microservice.

As David said in the comments, Bounded Contexts concept can (really) help you.

Anyway, imagine that you want to follow in that line which you're proposing. If a `Record` belongs to Microservice B and you have to reference it by composition somewhere in Microservice A, the only thing you'll need, is it's primary key. Not the whole object.

Would be something like this:

Microservice **A**:

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer grade;
    private Integer recordId;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Microservice **B**:

**Record.java**

```
public class Record {

    private Integer recordId;
    private List<Integer> marks;
    private Integer behaviourId;

    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And so on..

But as I said, maybe this is not the best approach.

See [**here**](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) a good article on Bounded Context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are clear on the bounded context aspect. Practically, it will be hard to review each and every class for having a relationship with each other as you have shown in your sample. I would suggest to use a tool that can visually show you the dependency. Then you after placing them into their bounded context you can begin the key mapping, to fetch data from other microservice(s).